# Match function in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to perform the following task using VBA: find a cell in table head that contains "Total number" title, return its column number, then find a cell on the intersection of raw with given number and column with returned number, and finally assign the value from this cell to a variable. Then wrote the value of this variable to another cell.

For example, suppose that the title "Total number" is in the AL column, then I'm trying to assign x = AL177 and then AM173 = x.

In a fact it is just a small part of more complex task, but unfortunately I can't deal with this fraction.

I wrote

```
Sub script()
Dim x As Integer
x = Cells(177, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Total number", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name").Range("2:2")))
Worksheet("sheet name").Range("AM173").Value = x
End Sub
```

I need to specify sheet name exactly (not just active sheet or something else) since some time later I'm going to execute it from another sheet.

When I try to run it Excel gives me an error:

> "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined"

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code and how it should be done?

Comment: when it errors, it highlights the problem. `Worksheet` should be `Worksheets`

Comment: @ScottCraner, thanks, I edited it at fourth string and now the error message says "Run time error 13: type mismatch" and highlights the third string where I'm trying to assign cell's value to a variable.

Comment: Is the value in the cell an integer?  If it is a string that looks like a number or a large number or an error you will get that.  Change x to variant and see it that works.

Comment: Also you are going to want to use the third criterion in the match: `...Range("2:2"),0))` to ensure an exact match.

Comment: @ScottCraner, thank you very much! Now everything is working as expected. The problem was that due to the lack of 0 as third argument it was trying to assign text from another cell in 177 raw to integer variable.